# Session register doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, session

I'm trying to make a login page. When I try to register the username as a session it should redirect me to another page, where it checks if that session is not registered. if it isn't, it redirects me back to the login page. well, i think it fails on the second page.

Login.php:

```
if($count==1){$_SESSION['user'] = $username;$_SESSION['pass'] = $password;header("location:Login_Success.php");}
else{echo "<p style='color:red'>Wrong username or password!</p>";}
```

login_success.php:

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['username'], $_SESSION['password'])){
header("location:login.php");}
```

**The error:** IT DOES NOT REGISTER THE SESSION! I know that because I replaced the  `header("location:url");` with an `echo "What the--?!"`, and it displayed "What the--?!".

## THE ANSWER

The session's value wasn't right. Here's the new code:

Login.php:

```
if($count==1){$_SESSION['user'] = "username" //Here was the problem
or die(mysql_error());header("location: Login_Success.php");}
else{echo "<p style='color:red;margin-left:150px;'>Wrong username or password!</p>";}
```

Login_Success.php:

```
session_start();
if($_SESSION['user']!="username")//"username" is here too
{header("location: login.php");}
```

Comment: Do you have `session_start();` in your `Login.php` page?

Comment: Yes, if you don't call it first then PHP doesn't look for any sessions.

Comment: @user2758781, Yes, you should include it, to get connected with the session itself.

Comment: Is $count ever set to 1? This should most likely be a session variable also ... $_SESSION['count']

Comment: it still isn't working with session_start() and yes, $count is set to one.

Comment: @user2758781, How is $count set to 1?

Comment: $count is a var that holds the number of rows found in a database.

Comment: Use `if(!isset($_SESSION['username'] || $_SESSION['password'])){` or `if(!isset($_SESSION['username'] && $_SESSION['password'])){`

Comment: and this will not work `header("location:Login_Success.php")` you need a space like this `header("location: Login_Success.php")`

Comment: but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

add

```
session_start();
```

at the begining of your pages.
even before doctype or any html code.
in fact before any printable code.

Comment: comment your ERROR message here.

Comment: so the problem is not your session, it something else in your code.

Comment: it's with the session. i first used a deprecated code and it gave me an error. i searched the net and found another method.

Comment: While you get no error message it means session has no problem, your if statement maybe never going to be true.
Make sure you set session variables currectly.
try to echo out your variables and sessions.
use print_r( $_SESSION );
and also add this error_reporting(1); at the begining of your files. may be helps to find out the problem

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `session_start();` on the begining of your code.

```
session_start(); //This will get you connected with your previous session

if($count==1){$_SESSION['user'] = $username;$_SESSION['pass'] = $password;header("location:Login_Success.php");}
else{echo "<p style='color:red'>Wrong username or password!</p>";}
```

Comment: my code's after the `<html>` tag. i thought `session_start()` must be placed before it.

Comment: @user2758781 Yes it should be.

Comment: but i wrote an `session_start();` on the beginning of the page, between `<?php?>` and it didn't work!

Comment: 'pastebin'? what's that? (don't laugh!)

Comment: No need to. I found out what the problem is. I wasn't using the right value!